# Which Firebird connection protocol should be fastest?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Which Firebird connection protocol should be fastest?

I have Delphi DataSnap aplication connected to Firebird 2.5 database at the same computer, runing on Windows.

Which protocol is fastest: TCP, named pipe or XNET.

For backup I am using gbak with `"-se service_mgr"` and that is more than twice faster in compare to gbak without `-se`. Does any of protocols work like gbak's `"-se service_mgr"`?

This example is without -se

```
"C:\Program files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\bin\GBAK" -b -v -limbo -ignore -garbage 127.0.0.1:c:\baze\baza.fdb c:\baze\baza.gbk
```

This example is with -se

```
"C:\Program files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\bin\GBAK" -b -v  -se service_mgr -limbo -ignore -garbage 127.0.0.1:c:\baze\baza.fdb c:\baze\baza.gbk
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, I'd strongly recommend that you do performance testing of your own application; that said XNET is probably the fastest.

Comment: Backup and protocols are different issues, no point to compare them. When you use services-based backup it is processed INSIDE the server process, so there is no protocols involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for comments Mark and Arioch.  I done some testing and XNET is twice faster then TCP.